# Convert C++ AlphaVSS DLL from framework 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert [AlphaVSS](http://alphavss.codeplex.com) to Framework 4.0, but when I try to compile I receive

```
error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest.
Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
<mypath>\AlphaVSS-1.0-Beta\Source\Obj\WinXP\x64\AlphaVSS.Platform.vcproj.dll.intermediate.manifest  AlphaVSS.Platform.vcproj.
```

What can I do?
I'd like to understand the reason and solve this problem (and maybe others similar).
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried googling the error code?

Comment: The .vcproj project file in the solution does not convert well.  I can't get this built without the VSS sdk installed so can't get to the stage where your build failed.  Considering the conversion problems, I'd have to recommend you use VS2008 only or wait until the project author finds some free time.  Post a bug report.

Comment: Btw, the path name of the manifest in the error message is bogus.  It should end at "manifest".

Comment: I googled error code, but problems and solutions are too different and I cannot take any advantage from them.
If I use VS2008 I cannot compile in NET4, and this is exactly what I need!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlphaVSS 1.2 beta1 is now released which targets the .NET 4 framework if you prefer not to use the App.config approach.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to recompile AlphaVSS using Visual Studio 2010 and Framework 4.0.
Anyway I was succesful in using my app:

1. Created a new app with framework 4.0 and referenced AlphaVSS dlls
2. Added an App.config file to my primary exe to run framework 2.0 assemblies
3. Installed VC++ Runtime 2008 on target machine

Here is app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.20506"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Hope this can help someone ...